# Macro Source or Definition

Tags: macros, context

How can I see the definition of the macro? I come from the programming background and it would be nice to see how the macro is defined. Perhaps even better if there would be something similar to Lisp's `macroexpand` and `macroexpand-1` commands. Is there a way to stop processing and leave a REPL for tex where I can run commands or get access to the current state of the processed document.

I looked at `\the`, `\show` and `\meaning` and I think `\meaning` is kind of close to what I was looking for. However it's not really showing me the macro definition in full. As for `latexdef` doesn't it just do text search in TEXMF directory ? This may not really work for dynamically defined macros and macros from modules outside of TEXMF.

I am asking this in the context of `ConTeXt` so perhaps the fact that it uses LuaTeX could be helpful for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you looking for `\show`? Or `latexdef`, which has to be typed on the terminal?

Comment: I'm not sure why you say that `\show` isn't showing the meaning of a macro: that's _exactly_ what it's doing

Comment: If you want the 'full trace', `\tracingall` is your friend (I hope you like long logs!)

Comment: I didn't get much luck with `\show`. Simple file 
```

\starttext
\show\strut
\stoptext
```
results in an error. `\tracingall` though is a good one to explore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run

```
mtxrun --silent --script context \
  --extra=meaning --once --noconsole --nostatistics \
  <command>
```

on the console. For instance

```
mtxrun --silent --script context \
  --extra=meaning --once --noconsole --nostatistics \
  setuplayout
```

Outputs:

```
meaning         > setuplayout

\protected macro:->\dodoubleempty \setup_layout
```

Comment: Oh, this one is fantastic !  I wonder if there's a way to also run some kind of REPL ?

Comment: @EvgeniySharapov You can run TeX interactively, but I never use that. For debugging ConTeXt has a lot to offer using  `\enabletrackers[…]` or `context --trackers=…`. List all trackers with: `context --showtrackers` But if that's useful depends on what you're actually after. For definitions I usually just grep the source.

Comment: How would I run `context` interactively ? I looked at [https://www.contextgarden.net/Console_Mode]() but it doesn't work. It just spits out `.tmp` file with TeX inside and quits.

Comment: @EvgeniySharapov You can use `context --pipe` to start an interactive session.